# hook_update_n not firing

Tags: 7, updating

Sorry for repeating this subject. I have studied previous and similar questions but I have been unable to resolve the issue.

I have a module with set to version 7.x-0.1 and I'm trying to execute a simple **hook_update_n** - but it's not executing.

I read that the [hook_update_n naming convent](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) has to be specific so I changed my module version to **7.x-1.0**

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
    function projecty_update_7101() {
    drupal_set_message("Executing Update#7101!");
}
```

I've tried a variety of number sequences but no joy.

**The schema_version for my module in the systems database table is set to 0.**

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you putting the hook implementation? It needs to go in the module's .install file...

Comment: @Clive: yes, it's in the .install file. It's below the schema hook but I don't imagine that is the problem

Comment: And the module is called `projecty` (i.e. the file it's in is called `projecty.install`, and you've cleared the caches since adding the new hook?

Comment: @Clive: No. The install file is named projectY.install. The schema hook executed under that name though

Comment: Hmm it probably _is_ running then, I guess the message is getting lost in the redirects. Try `return 'test';` instead, that should give you a message when you get to the end of the update procedure (you can reset things by putting your module's schema back down to 0 in the database)

Comment: @Clive: included 'return 'test' in update function, cleared cache and executed update.php. hook_update_n still not firing

Comment: I would try naming your file with proper casing (i.e. that matches the name of the module properly) and try that - I can't think of anything else, as your code should work

Comment: @Clive: you were right. That single capital letter in the module name was throwing everything off balance. I edited all the files changing the single instance capital Y to lowercase and it now recognises the update hook. Go ahead and provide an answer and I'll give the due credit. Thanks for your help